# Why am I not getting the correct output for my c++ code?

Tags: c++, arrays, exception, output

So the c++ code that I'm writing basically takes an array and inserts values in the array while shifting it right to make space and if the array is full then it makes a new array that copies the old values from the first array into the second. Here's the code that does that:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "dynamic_array.h"

using namespace std;

dynamic_array::dynamic_array() {
    size = 0;
    allocated_size = 0;
    try {
        array = new int [size + BLOCK_SIZE];    
    } catch (bad_alloc){
        throw exception (MEMORY_EXCEPTION);
    }
}

dynamic_array::~dynamic_array() {
    delete []array;
}

int dynamic_array::get_size(void) const {
    return size;
}

int dynamic_array::get_allocated_size(void) const {
    return allocated_size;
}

int& dynamic_array::operator[](unsigned int i) {
    if (i >= (unsigned)get_size()){
        throw exception(SUBSCRIPT_RANGE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    return array[i];
}

const int& dynamic_array::operator[](unsigned int i) const {
    if (i < 0 || i > (unsigned)get_size()){
        throw exception(SUBSCRIPT_RANGE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    return array[i];
}

void dynamic_array::insert(int x, int i) {
    if (get_size() == get_allocated_size()){
        int *new_array = new int[get_allocated_size() + BLOCK_SIZE]; 
        allocated_size = allocated_size + BLOCK_SIZE;
        for (int i = 0; i < get_size(); i++){
            new_array[i] = array[i];
        }
        delete []array;
        array = new_array;
    }
    try {
        shift_right(i, get_size() - 1, 1);
        array[i] = x;
        size = size + 1;
    } catch (bad_alloc){
        throw exception (MEMORY_EXCEPTION);
    }
    if (i < 0 or i > get_size()){
        throw exception(SUBSCRIPT_RANGE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    return;
}

void dynamic_array::shift_right(int start, int end, int delta){
    try{
        for(int i=start; i<end; i++){
            array[i+delta] = array[i];
        }
    } catch (bad_alloc){
        throw exception (MEMORY_EXCEPTION);
    }
    return;
}
```

The variables are declared the the constructor class

```
    BLOCK_SIZE = 5,
    SUBSCRIPT_RANGE_EXCEPTION = 1,
    MEMORY_EXCEPTION = 2,
int *array; // pointer to dynamically allocated memory
int allocated_size; // total number of elements in allocated memory
int size; // number of active elements
```

To test the code I use this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "dynamic_array.h"

using namespace std;

int test_const_operator(const dynamic_array &a, int i) {
    return a[i];
}

void print_array(dynamic_array &a) {
    cout << "size: " << a.get_size() << endl;
    cout << "allocated size: " << a.get_allocated_size() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.get_size(); i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    dynamic_array a;

    cout << "***** array size: 0" << endl;
    print_array(a);

    cout << "check for exception in empty array" << endl;
    try {
        a[0];
    } catch (dynamic_array::exception x) {
        cout << "caught: " << x.n << endl;
    }
    try {
        test_const_operator(a, 0);
    } catch (dynamic_array::exception x) {
        cout << "caught const: " << x.n << endl;
    }

    cout << "***** array size: 1" << endl;
    a.insert(2,0);
    cout << test_const_operator(a, 0) << endl;
    print_array(a);

    cout << "***** array size: 2" << endl;
    a.insert(4,1);
    print_array(a);

    cout << "***** array size: 3" << endl;
    a.insert(3,1);
    print_array(a);

    cout << "***** trigger subscript range exception" << endl;
    try {
        a.insert(5,4);
    } catch (dynamic_array::exception x) {
        cout << "caught: " << x.n << endl;
    }

    cout << "***** trigger re-allocation" << endl;
    a.insert(1,0);
    a.insert(5,4);
    a.insert(99,2);
    print_array(a);
}
```

Now the output I get when I run this code is:

```
***** 
array size: 0

size: 0

allocated size: 0


check for exception in empty array

caught: 1

***** 
array size: 1
2

size: 1

allocated size: 5
2 

***** 
array size: 2

size: 2

allocated size: 5
2 4 

***** 
array size: 3

size: 3

allocated size: 5
2 3 0 

***** 
trigger subscript range exception

***** 
trigger re-allocation
size: 7
allocated size: 10
1 2 99 2 2 2 1
```

But that's not the output I want. Here the things that I was supposed to get:

```
caught: 1

caught const: 1
```

There was no caught const on line 7. On line 18 it was supposed to say `allocated size: 52 3 4` but instead it said `allocated size: 52 3 0`. After it said `trigger subscript range exception`it was supposed to say `caught: 1` underneath it but for mine it doesn't say anything. Finally on the second to last line it was supposed to say size:6 instead of size:7. And the last line was supposed to say `allocated size: 101 2 99 3 4 5`. So I'm really close in getting the correct output but I'm still a little confused about these last few bits and how to get the correct output. To run the code I'm also using a .h file that looks like this:

```
using namespace std;

class dynamic_array {
public:
    enum {
        BLOCK_SIZE = 5,
        SUBSCRIPT_RANGE_EXCEPTION = 1,
        MEMORY_EXCEPTION = 2,
    };

    /*Purpose
    *   create an array with size 0
    * Preconditions
    *   none
    * Exceptions
    *   if there is not enough dynamic memory available
    *       throw exception(MEMORY_EXCEPTION)
    */
    dynamic_array();

    /*Purpose
    *   create an array containing a copy of the elements in a
    * Preconditions
    *   none
    * Exceptions
    *   if there is not enough dynamic memory available
    *       throw exception(MEMORY_EXCEPTION)
    */

    int get_size(void) const;

    /*Purpose
    *   return the allocated size of the array
    * Preconditions
    *   none
    * Exceptions
    *   none
    */
    int get_allocated_size() const;

    /*Purpose
    *   return a reference to the element with index i
    * Preconditions
    *   none
    * Exceptions
    *   if i >= get_size()
    *       throw exception(SUBSCRIPT_RANGE_EXCEPTION)
    */
    int& operator[](unsigned int i);
    /*Purpose
    *   return a reference to the element with index i
    * Preconditions
    *   none
    * Exceptions
    *   if i >= get_size()
    *       throw exception(SUBSCRIPT_RANGE_EXCEPTION)
    */
    const int& operator[](unsigned int i) const;

    /*Purpose
    *   insert x at postion i
    *   shift elements at positions i and higher one position to the right
    * Preconditions
    *   none
    * Exceptions
    *   if i < 0 or i > get_size()
    *       throw exception(SUBSCRIPT_RANGE_EXCEPTION)
    *   if there is not enough dynamic memory available
    *       throw exception(MEMORY_EXCEPTION)
    */
    void insert(int x, int i);

    /*Purpose
    *   insert the elements of a at postion i
    *   shift elements at positions i and higher n positions to the right
    *       where n is the size of a
    * Preconditions
    *   none
    * Exceptions
    *   if i < 0 or i > get_size()
    *       throw exception(SUBSCRIPT_RANGE_EXCEPTION)
    *   if there is not enough dynamic memory available
    *       throw exception(MEMORY_EXCEPTION)
    */

    class exception {
        public:
            exception(int n0) { n = n0; };
            int n;
    };
private:
    /*purpose
    *   shift array[start..end-1] delta positions to the left
    * preconditions
    *   0 <= start <= end <= size
    *   array[start-delta..end-delta-1] legally addressable
    * examples
    *   given array with contents {0,2,4,6,8, 10,12,14,16,18}:
    *       shift(2,4,2)
    *           changes the contents to {4,6,4,6,8, 10,12,14,16,18}
    *       shift(2,2,1)
    *           leaves array unchanged
    */
    void shift_right(int start, int end, int delta);

    int *array; // pointer to dynamically allocated memory
    int allocated_size; // total number of elements in allocated memory
    int size; // number of active elements
};
```

Comment: I hope this is just to learn, an exercise? Because duplicating `std::vector` would be just stupid otherwise. :) Oh, and you should really learn about [the rules of three, five and zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: I've never used c++ before. I know Java pretty well but this is one of the first c++ codes that I have to write.

Comment: I suggest you post a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: By the way, why don't you have `get_size` return an `unsigned int`? It's not like the size could ever be negative.

Comment: Also, in the `operator[]` function, what is the purpose of `dynamic_array(array)`? That will create a *temporary* object that is immediately discarded. Also, you *do* have the right constructor for this? Please include the class definition in your question.

Comment: @JoshSusa If you never used C++ before you should start with simpler programs. And it is worth spending more time learning the language.

Comment: All I want to know are these little things for my output. I'll try and go back and make the code more efficient in the run time but for now all I'm trying to do is fix these little differences in the output. My output is almost the output that I want but there's just a few small differences.

Comment: You keep changing the code in the question, how can we be certain that the code you show is actually the code you run? Are *you* certain that the code you show is the code you actually run? You *did* re-build after adding the second try-catch?

Comment: First code is the class. The second one is the code that I run. The second code produces the output however like I said it's missing lines that should be there like caught const: 1 should appear after the first time it says caught: 1. Why isn't that line appearing in my output?

Comment: We can't say. Like I asked, are you sure the code you show is actually the code you run? Do you build with any kind of optimization (because the function call doesn't really do anything, there's no side-effects and no result that is stored so it could be completely optimized away)? Try to turn off optimizations completely, with e.g. GCC add the argument `-O0` when building (and remove any other `-O` argument).

Comment: I'm also using a .h file which is used when I run the code. I can post that here but that file's also kind of long.

Comment: Your `shift_right` is copying elements starting at the left end. Write `1 2 3` on  a piece of paper and do that by hand to see why it is wrong.

Comment: So it's copying instead of just shifting?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't getting the `"const caught"` output because `const int& dynamic_array::operator[](unsigned int i) const` isn't throwing an exception.

That function gets called with `i` set to 0, and the test for throwing the exception is:

```
if (i < 0 || i > (unsigned)get_size()){
    throw exception(SUBSCRIPT_RANGE_EXCEPTION);
}
```

which isn't true when `i == 0`.

You don't even experience undefined behavior because when `size == 0` the `array` member actually points to an allocation with 5 elements (because  `BLOCK_SIZE = 5`) so there actually is an `array[0]` element.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that, must be too early in the morning. :) It *should* generate a compiler warning, since `i` can't actually be less than zero.

Comment: But if I add i==0 then I get an error that says "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'dynamic_array::exception' Aborted (core dumped).

Comment: I assume that you see the "const caught" then get the "terminate called..." right?  If you look a few lines after where you output `"***** array size: 1"` you're calling `test_const_operator(a, 0)` outside of a `try`/`catch`.  If you throw an exception when `i==0` regardless of the size of the array then that call will throw and there's nothing to catch the exception there.  You need to carefully think through the logic of when  `dynamic_array::operator[](unsigned int i) const` should throw.